# Package appears in Software Center but is not installable

Tags: 12.04, software-center, synaptic, teamspeak

I am testing 12.04.1 64 Bit and tried to install the Teamspeak package via Software Center:

[image]

After clicking on "More Info" since the "Install" button was not there I got the following:

[image]

After doing a bit of more search, in Synaptic I found that the package does appear but it mentions it is for 32 Bit only:

[image]

So why does it show on Software Center in the first place if it is only for 32 Bit.

Comment: It appears because there is a package for Teamspeak, but then you get Not Found because it's for 32 bit, that's what i think.

Comment: Same thinking but if we look at it from the End user perspective it will confuse the heck out of anybody new to it. I thought Software Center could somehow differentiate between the apps it had for 32 Bit and for 64 Bit. Or at least a message saying the architecture it was build for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been confirmed as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/999301) for software-center which may be resolved in future updates.

Comment: Well that took long. I was looking for it in the same place but could not find it. Thank you ignite.